# How to log ip address on JBoss

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

I want to log the IP address of the client who is calling my WS.

How can I do that on JBoss?

EDIT:

I would like to use log4J configuration on JBOSS if possible.

Answer (score 7):

Append the following to your conversion pattern parameter in log4j configuration xml.

```
%X{RemoteAddress}
```

And in your code you can log the ip address as follows:

```
MDC.put("RemoteAddress", request.getRemoteAddr())
```

Comment: The code should also "unset" the MDC once the request has completed.

Comment: Here is a short article on the use of MDC in jboss: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/LoggingContextualInformation

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://community.jboss.org/thread/101432), in case you are provind functionality via EJB3.

Comment: Thx for the answer. 
But I am not using EJB3, and I would like to log it using log4j conf on jboss