# Get IP address in JBoss Web Service

Tags: web-services, jboss, jbossws, java-web-start

I developed a java class with an only method and turned into web service (JBOSS) using JBossWS. I would like to get the IP address of the client who started the request. (I'm not using jsp)

```
public String getMyIP() {
  //get IP from client from current request
  // return IP as String
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to point out that this question is different from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346365/how-to-log-ip-address-on-jboss
I tried but don't know how to get the request object MDC.put("RemoteAddress", request.getRemoteAddr())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

First set this resource in the class:

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

Then use this code on your class:

```
SOAPMessageContext jaxwsContext = (SOAPMessageContext)wsContext.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest request = HttpServletRequest)jaxwsContext.get(SOAPMessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```