# Getting the server's IP address in MicroProfile

Tags: java, microprofile

In a MicroProfile project I have a FallbackHandler like this:

```
public class RestFallbackHandler implements FallbackHandler<Response> {
    public Response handle(ExecutionContext context) {
        // code here
    }
```

I would like to send in Response the server's IP address.

I tried this way:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/7430038/2595658

But `wsContext.getMessageContext()` is null.

Does MicroProfile have other way to get the IP address at the fallback handler level?